# how get element from grid

Tags: extjs, grid, datastore

I have grid in extjs program. Grid has 2 columns. I want to get each value in grid.
Is possible something like that (of course in JS):

```
foreach( row in grid ) {
     row.cell[0] // do something 
     row.cell[1] // do something
}
```

If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using other user answer I know how do it in extjs 3.3.1 (user863680's solution doesn't work in my program).

```
gridName.getStore().each(function(rec){  // for each row

                        var rowData = rec.data; // get record
                        alert( rowData['col1Name'] ); // get value from cell
                        alert( rowData['col2Name'] );   

                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access each row in your grid, you could do the following.

```
yourGrid.getStore().each(function(rec){
    var rowData = rec.data;
    for (var i=0; i<rowData.length; i++) {
        console.log(rowData[i]); //or you could do something else here
    };
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I got error, that rowData.length is undefined, also rowData[i] is undefined

Comment: Ok, I know now how to do it (using your answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
alert("Getting grid value = "+document.getElementById("yourgridblock").rows[1].cells[2].firstChild.value);

alert("Getting grid value = "+document.getElementById("yourgridblk").rows[1].cells[0].firstChild.checked);

alert("Getting grid count = "+document.getElementById("yourgridblk").rows.length);
```